# How can <p> display a variable

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Is there any way that I can load a variable in a 'p' tag?

In my test.html.erb:

```
<p>"#{@variable}"</p>
```

And in my test_controller.rb

```
@variable = "Testing"
```

However, in the html, it displays "#{@variable}".

How should I fix it?

Comment: `html.erb` files use [ERB](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html)

Comment: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to print your code and then to interpolate it, try with:

```
<p><%= "#{@variable}" %></p>
```

Or just `<p><%= @variable %></p>`, depending on what you want to do, then you can interpolate your variables.

With `<p>"#{@variable}"</p>` you're just printing plain html, nothing is being interpreted by Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
<%= @variable %>
```